# osx can't create android virtual devices

Tags: android-studio, osx-lion, android-virtual-device

osx 10.7 android studio 1.2RC april 17th build.  Using the avd in android studio results in a crash, and using the avd manager from the adt bundle eventually results in an error message related to being unable to create the sd card image.

I've run sudo android avd in order to try to overcome this and no luck.  I just updated android studio and had tried running a virtual device i'd created a while back.  after all my ram was consumed with android studio, java, and the emulator with just a black screen, I restarted the machine and tried again, and tried to tweak my existing virtual device to consume less ram and so forth.  avd in android studio crashed, then I lost all my existing virtual devices, and I can't seem to create a new one.  I've used the sdk manager to update to the latest version of the bundle, and I've made sure that I have the arm and x86 system images for the virtual device api level I'm trying to make.

This is how my android experience has gone.  spend a few hours downloading and installing all the tools and get nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are a million ways to do any one thing with this tool suite.  Using the command line ./android create avd helped me get past this one.  Hopefully future usage of the other two paths doesn't wipe out my avds again.